# Trimming Strings within C# .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

new enough to C#.

Just can't get my head around trimming with a string. I want to be able to trim the whitespace after the string as it is messing up my database with the amount of whitespace I get. Here's one of my entities that I'd like to do it in.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters and numbers only please")]
[Display(Name = "Serial Number ")]
public string SerialNo
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            string serialNumber = SerialNo.Trim();
            return serialNumber;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return SerialNo;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.SerialNo = SerialNo;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm going about this all wrong so some help would be appreciated!

EDIT: My error is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PhotocopierInformationManagementServices.dll"

Comment: Have you tried this code? It looks like three different ways to generate a stack overflow.

Comment: That's [too new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to C#. TLDR; you lack property backing field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will end up in **stackoverflow excption** as it will keep executing infinitely, as the set block is getting called again and due to `this.SerialNo=` inside the `set` block:

```
set
{
    this.SerialNo = SerialNo; // calling set of SerialNo recursively
}
```

you can change your code to be :

```
private string _serialNo;
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters and numbers only please")]
[Display(Name = "Serial Number ")]
public string SerialNo
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            _serialNo= _serialNo.Trim();
            return _serialNo;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return _serialNo;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _serialNo= value;
    }
}
```

But i would recommend to trim it in setter so that your property would look now like:

```
private string _serialNo;
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters and numbers only please")]
[Display(Name = "Serial Number ")]
public string SerialNo
{
    get
    {
        return _serialNo;
    }
    set
    {
        _serialNo= value?.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: For bonus points, the `get` method also seems to aim for stack overflow in two different ways. For the "Stack Overflows per line of code" metric, I think this might be a winner.

Comment: Stupid question but what way would you fix it?

Comment: @KOD459 i have written how it would be fixed

Comment: If you're going to use `catch` at least catch `NullReferenceException`, but IMHO, null-checks should be explicit, rather than waiting for an exception and catching it.

Answer (score 2):

You use C# Property wrong. Use my example:

```
private string serialNumber;

public string SerialNo
{
    get { return serialNumber; }
    set { serialNumber = value?.Trim(); }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer, but it does rely on newer C# functionality. If you find yourself not being allowed to use `value?.Trim()`, then the version of C# you're using doesn't support that. Alternatively you can use a ternary: `value != null ? value.Trim() : null`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with trimming, but with the fact that on set you are recursively calling get. The correct syntax is

```
private string serialNo;

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters and numbers only please")]
[Display(Name = "Serial Number ")]
public string SerialNo
{
    get
    {
        return serialNo;
    }
    set
    {
        this.serialNo = value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try string serialNumber = SerialNo.TrimEnd();?

If that does not work try SerialNo.Replace(" ", "");

Comment: And for learning purposes, you can also use `TrimStart()` too. I've had to depend on that a few times in the past.

Comment: Didn't work, I get the same error as I've been getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PhotocopierInformationManagementServices.dll"

Comment: `SerialNo.Anything` from within the `SerialNo` property is recursive.. it will re-enter the `SerialNo` property forever. This is what is causing the overflow as the other answer states.